# Send caps text to a text box using Robot class & Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, awtrobot

How to send capital text to a text box using Robot class and Selenium WebDriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things to:

**1- First to get focus to the textfield, where you want to enter the value, like this:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath of the element")).sendKeys("")// id or class can be used as locators too.
```

**2- Then use 'Robot class' to send values to the field (using CAPSLOCK or SHIFT keys for changing the letters to uppercase).**

Try this code. It works for **sending "HELLO" (all caps) in Google.com's search field** using **"CAPSLOCK"**:

```
//Navigating to the site
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

//To get the focus on the searchbox (NOT ENTERING ANYTHING)
driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("");

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_H);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
```

**OR** you can try using **"SHIFT"** as below:

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_H);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send caps text to a text box using Robot class in following manner. 
Below i am sending  String OK using Robot class

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_K); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_K);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying.how do we get this caps text to be input into a text box.I tried the same as u suggested along with sendKeys, it did not work.

Comment: @dev: Does it Worked ? If not can you show me your implementation for the same?

Comment: This can be really messy, pls don't mind. My only focus is to get the capital text in the username text box using robot.Its getting printed in caps now in the address bar when I launch firefox. But my goal is to send it to username field. Please help.

Comment: For the username field you will have to detect the input box by any of the method.(id,xpath or css) and send the capital text by using sendKeys funtion. Here is the example. driver.findelement(by.id(---****)).sendkeys( CAPITAL TEXT);

Comment: Also if the above code has worked for you then mark it as answer.

Comment: I do know the usage of sendKeys.What I have been trying to do is, send caps text using robot class to the username text box. Its getting typed in CAPS in the address bar following the url , when the automated test is run.I don't know how to get robot to type in the text box.This is the issue.

Comment: I understand its not needed to use Robot class in this scenario. We can easily do a senKeys .I am just trying to understand if it's possible to do using Robot.

Comment: Yes,Its Possible just you have to  use robot.mouseMove(x, y);   where x and y are  screen coordinates and then the regular key events.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using "Caps Lock" or "Shift" key, that code has been mentioned here in another answer by Subh.

You can also do it by using StringSelection in Java. The code is as below:

```
//First of all declare the method setClipboardData as below:
public void setClipboardData(String string) {
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(string);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
    }
//Call the method setClipboardData and write other Robot code:
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("");

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        setClipboardData("ALL CAPS");
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```